# Installing OpenCL for AMD in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, driver, opencl, amd-gpu

I want to make some GPU computations for my project using OpenCL.
But I have faced some troubles with installation of it.
First of all, I don't know how to install the appropriate driver for my video card.

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R2 Graphics]
```

There are information on a few forums that there is no official driver for AMD cards. So how can I handle it?

Can anybody tell what I should do?

It is said that this site [https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers](https://launchpad.net/%7Eoibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) has some drivers

Is it enough commands to install a driver?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ROCm](https://rocm.github.io/ROCmInstall.html) or [AmdGpu-Pro](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx). Back when Ubuntu 16.04 was released there really was no driver. At that time only downgrading to 14.04 and using the AMD Catalyst driver allowed you to utilize OpenCL on the GPU.